# Multiple inputs on one line with multiple variables and with double digit numbers (Derivative Calculator)

Tags: java

```
package DerivativeFormulas;

import Variables.Variables;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PowerRule {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //User inputs derivative equation
    System.out.print("Enter the derivative - ");
    Variables.userInputs = Variables.input.readLine().split("");


    //Coefficient is put into the string array "userInputs"
    Variables.coefficient = Integer.parseInt(Variables.userInputs[0]);

    //User inputs the variable assigned to function
    String x;
    x = Variables.userInputs[1];

    //User inputs power symbol "^"
    String power;
    power = Variables.userInputs[2];


    Variables.polydeg = Integer.parseInt(Variables.userInputs[3]);

    System.out.println((Variables.coefficient * Variables.polydeg) + x + power + (Variables.polydeg - 1));
  }
}
```

I was trying to make a program that would take the derivative of a function using the power rule. The user inputs a leading coefficient, then a variable, then the power symbol "^", and then the exponent of the variable without any spaces in between. The input is all on one line. `4x^2 outputs 8x^1` The program is successful only when the user input for leading coefficient and the exponent are < 10. Whenever I try to input a double digit number for the coefficient or the exponent, I get an error. I can get the program to work when I put spaces in between the inputs by changing `.split("")` to `.split(" ")` , but I don't want any spaces in between the inputs. For example `10x^10` will not work. How do I fix this?

Here are the variables too.

```
package Variables;

import java.io.*;

public class Variables {

    //Main user input
    public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    //User inputs get put into a string array
    public static String userInputs[] = new String[4];

    //Numbers
    public static int coefficient;
    public static int polydeg;

    //Symbols
    public static char e = 'e';

}
```

Comment: So your input is guaranteed to be in the format of `ax^b` with a, b being integers?

Comment: Quick suggestion: don't split. Use `indexOf('x')` and `indexOf('^')` to find constant characters, then use `substring` to extract coefficient and exponent.

Comment: @jrook Yep! it's just that I can't get a or b to be a double digit number.

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: you really don't need the `Variable` class. Scanning one line from the input and storing it as a string can also be done inside `main`.

Comment: @jrook Yeah I just did it for my own sake. I wanted the code to be a little bit more neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in the expression `ax^b` `a` and `b` could be multiple digits, `split()` probably isn't the best tool for this. You could use the [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) and [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) functions instead to extract the numbers:

```
String temp = Example.input.readLine();
Example.userInputs[0] =  temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf("x"));
Example.userInputs[1] = "x";  
Example.userInputs[2] = "^";
Example.userInputs[3] = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("^") +1, temp.length());
```